# How to make data-modal work inside setTimeout function JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run into a problem, I need to use `setTimeout` inside another (larger) function, but this one bellow won't work if put it inside:

```
$('#'+$(this).data('modal')).show();
```

How to make it work inside `setTimeout` function like this one:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#'+$(this).data('modal')).show(); });
```

Any ideas?

// I need it to be setTimeout only, no other option like .delay(), etc. is no go.

// Without setTimeout it works perfectly with:

`$('.modal-trigger').on('click', function(){`

and `data-modal="modal-identificator"` inside `button` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, your callback is not aware of `this`. Try doing it like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#'+$(this).data('modal')).show();
}.bind(this), 5000);
```

Comment: Where should I "put" delay time in your example, before or after `.bind(this)`, can you please update your answer with delay time?

Comment: Thank You!, it solved this issue. Does `.bind()` inside this example may cause **additional** delay, since it is at the bottom? (if `setTimeout` function contains not one but several "tasks" to do)

Comment: Ill think you will be fine. It is binded only once, when the callback is executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("#modal").modal("show").on("shown", function () {
         window.setTimeout(function () {
         }, 5000);
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your setTimout function, $(this) references to another context. to Solve your problem, I think it should be enough if you store your $(this) variable in an local variable:

```
let _this = $(this);
setTimeout(function() {....}
```